# sql server compact edition features

Tags: stored-procedures, view, sql-server-ce, capability

Does anyone know where I can find a list of supported features for SQL Server Compact Edition? I am interested in using the new version with my web app but am trying to determine if it can do what I need? specifically I want to know if it can support views and stored procedures but the microsoft site was futile.

thanks in advance

Edit:

I looked at this [SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) but it was not helpful to me.

Comment: Are you talking about SQL CE 4 Beta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server CE 4 does not support stored procedures, as you can read in [this blog post by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx):

> SQL CE is an embedded database – which
>   makes it ideal for development and
>   light-usage scenarios.  For
>   high-volume sites and applications
>   you’ll probably want to migrate it to
>   use SQL Server Express (which is
>   free), SQL Server or SQL Azure.  These
>   servers enable much better
>   scalability, more development features
>   (**including features like Stored
>   Procedures – which aren’t supported
>   with SQL CE**), as well as more advanced
>   data management capabilities.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) has a complete list of the difference between CE and SQL Server. It says that both stored procedures and views are not supported by CE.