# Does SQL Server Compact Edition supports Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Does SQL Server Compact Edition supports Stored Procedures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285417/sql-server-compact-edition-features

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/02/11/stored-procedures-and-sql-server-compact-the-great-debate.aspx

No.